# SSLError: SSL validation failed for https:/s3/endpoints/invocations EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396) in sagemaker

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

I trained a deep neural network using sagemaker and deployed the endpoint successfully. But, when trying to get the predictions on test data, i am getting "SSLError: SSL validation failed for [https://runtime.s3.amazonaws.com/endpoints/[endpointName]/invocations](https://runtime.s3.amazonaws.com/endpoints/%5BendpointName%5D/invocations) EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396)"

i am able to get predictions up to 10 records, afterwards i am getting this error.please help me.

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlowPredictor
predictor = TensorFlowPredictor(endpoint_name)

# invoke model endpoint to make inference
pred = predictor.predict(input_vals)
    
# store predictions
y_pred.extend([i[0] for i in pred['predictions']])
```

Comment: More details on the code and endpoint are needed to answer this question.

Comment: Endpoint is configured in VPC and there is VPC interface endpoint added to access the sagemaker runtime